# Accelerator pedal goes to the floor sporadically while driving

Tags: chrysler, acceleration, lebaron

One of my cars is a 1987 Chrysler LeBaron GTS, which originally belonged to my mother, and has only 30,000 miles on it. Occasionally, the accelerator pedal will go to the floor. (My mother took excellent care of the car - garaged -so much so that it looks factory new.)  The first time this happened to me was last winter when I was coming off the exit ramp of the interstate. It was a long downhill ride to the light.  I lightly put my foot on the accelerator to keep at the 30 mph exit speed, and suddenly the pad went right to the floor. As soon as I applied the break the car slowed down.  It freaked me out but I chalked it up as an anomaly due to icy roads even though the car had studded snow tires (2 years old).  Then, a few months later it happened again while on the highway. I immediately took it to my mechanic who could find nothing wrong. Even the floor mats were not in the way. Despite all that this still happens, and has been increasing in frequency to the point where I no longer drive the car. Today, my sister went on line and read at the Car Guy that the first sign of a transmission going is when the accelerator pedal goes straight to the floor.  Is this true and if so can anything be done short of replacing the transmission?  Quite honestly, I don't want to waste money on a car this old and will sell it to a collector instead.  But, I happen to like the car and the way it handles, so would prefer to keep it if it doesn't cost me an arm and leg to do so. Any ideas besides this that can help me figure this out?  Thanks for any advice and ideas.

Comment: If you are looking to sell the car, check out turbo-mopar.com and turbododge.com for people interested in these vehicles.  Last I saw, they weren't worth too much, but the low mileage helps.

Answer (score 6):

From your description, it sounds like there is an issue with the cruise control. If the cruise control "thought" you wanted to accelerate for whatever reason, it would do exactly as you stated and peg the gas to the floor. Then, when you apply the brakes, it would tell the cruise to shut down. I don't remember how the cruise is actuated on the LeBaron, but IIRC, it's on the turn signal. I wouldn't know if it would be the control or the unit which would be causing the issue, but needless to say, I think I'd unplug it (in the engine bay) until you can have a mechanic look at it. The last thing you need is for uncontrolled acceleration to be going on when you are just trying to tool down the lane. Could get ugly really quick.

Comment: This seems like the most plausible explanation. Issues with the transmission or the drivetrain wouldn't change the resistance of the accelerator.

Comment: Bingo, I think you just found the problem for me.  I didn't even know I had it on this car as I never bothered to read the manual. The turn signal on this car also has the windshield wipers, and to the right of that is cruise control, except it's called speed control, and it was in the ON position.   Would that be the reason, after decelerating off a highway from 65 to 25 then depressing the accelerator to increase speed would cause the pedal to go down on it's own?  According to the manual, the original speed would stay in memory after I pressed on the brake.

Comment: @Ana   That is correct.  The memory of the last rate of speed would be kept in the cruise control and if it were engaged the cruise would attempt to get the vehicle back to it's prior speed.  Also, I checked the government recall site for you vehicle.  There were no hits regarding a recall for the condition you described.

Comment: What I know for sure is that the cruise control was in the ON position. According to the manual, I would have to push the control slide to the Resume position to reengage the system. But, as I didn't even realize this car had this feature I never did that. All I can assume is that I did something when using the wipers which is also where the control is located further up the same stick. (Continued next posting)

Comment: According to the manual 'when you reach the desired speed you move the control to the ON position. This will establish memory and activate the system'. But the manual also says that breaking will deactivate the system without erasing the memory and I would have to push Resume to reactivate Speed Control. Only by 'Pushing the control to the OFF position or turning off the ignition erases the speed memory'. If that is the case then why would the system reactivate upon ignition simply by having the switch in the ON position?

Comment: Not sure, likely a fault in the system.  It should not reengage without moving the slider to the 'resume' position.